# Modeling a chess board in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, chess

I'm learning wxPython to make a chess GUI, but I don't exactly know how it should be done, what widgets to use. I'm thinking that I make every square a button with the piece's picture and then position them on the board right next to each other, so I have 64 buttons on the board.

When I move one piece, I put the button on the target square and the origin square will then be replaced with a button which represents an empty square.

Is this the right way to do it in wxPython? I'm really stuck here, as there are no examples on the web for a chess GUI in wxPython.

Comment: Sounds like you have a decent idea of how to implement it, and just need the confidence to go forward. We believe in you :-)

Comment: this is way too broad... but no i would not do that ... I would use the DrawingDC to make the board and then i would setup each piece in its own panel and move it around the board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, creating a chess program with wxPython was how I taught myself python programming, some ten years ago ;-) Good luck.

First you will need to draw the grid for the board. This is easy. Then you will need a datastructure to remember the positions of all the pieces. For this I used the module here: http://www.alcyone.com/pyos/chess/. Next you need a routine that given a `Board` will draw the pieces at the appropriate locations.

To move the chess pieces, you will probably want to use drag and drop. This way, you can make a square (or the piece that is drawn on that square) draggable. You will need to a routine to calculate the square from your screen coordinates e.g. `screen_to_board()` . On the drop event you will calculate the target square using this same routine. Then you simply update the board state (use `Board.move()`) and redraw the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how would i draw the grid? What i'm having trouble understanding is how should i represent the chess pieces (or the 64 squares that have pictures on them). As buttons?

Comment: I would not use buttons. I simply drew the grid on a canvas. This can be done by getting the device context and then calling `DrawLine()` and `FillSquare()` repeatedly. (I am quoting from memory.) For the chess pieces, I took the images in the winboard/Xboard packages and simply drew them over the grid on the canvas. I think I used something like `dc.DrawBitmap()`.

Comment: +1: I like the idea of a system where you can drag and drop the pieces, and this would require a canvas, such as in DragImage in the wx demo.  (Buttons might work if you only wanted to click, but what should happen when you click.  Pieces want to be moved.)

Comment: Ok, i'm gonna try to figure something out using the information i gave you. If i run into trouble, which i will,  i'll just ask another question . Thank you very much :d .